# Remove last portions of a string that is following a specific delimiter

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have strings that looks like these

`aa-bbb-cc-d-ff-eee-gg`
`aa-bb-ccc-d`
`aaa-bbbb`

They are delimited via the dash symbol `-`.

Now I want to trim the last portion of these kind of strings and come up with something like

- from `aa-bbb-cc-d-ff-eee-gg` to `aa-bbb-cc-d` //removed 3 parts
- from `aa-bb-ccc-d` to `aa-bb` //removed 2 parts
- from `aaa-bbbb` to `aaa` //removed 1 part

so on and so forth. The amount of portions to remove is also defined.

I am aware that I can just loop through the length of these strings by splitting them and concatenating them like a madman.

```js
function splitParts(str, parts){
   let len = str.split('-').length;
   let output = "";

   for(let i = 0; i < len - parts; i++){
       output += !i ? str.split('-')[i] : "-" + str.split('-')[i];
   }

   return output;
}

console.log(splitParts("aa-bb-ccc-dd-eee", 1))
```

But I find it painfully inelegant and amateurish. Is there any other way to do this better? Preferably one liners that works with IE11. But other approaches that doesn't just hack through the splitted parts will also work.

Comment: What do you mean by _last portion_? I see that sometimes you remove 3 blocks, sometimes 2 and also 1 part. What's the logic?

Comment: @molamk `The amount of portions to remove is also defined.`. I think we can consider it to be like a function parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have an array of the alphabetical characters, you can `slice` the desired portion of the array (dropping the unneeded parts) and then join by `-`s:

```js
const str = "aa-b-ccc-gg-dddd-e";
const arr = str.split('-');
const parts = 1;

const output = arr
  .slice(0, arr.length - parts)
  .join('-');
console.log(output)
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. It's not as short as I truly wanted it to be but it's certainly miles better than what I came up with. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var abc='sad-ioioiio-sdsd';
var cd=abc.split('-');
cd.splice(-1,1);
console.log(cd.join('-'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But unfortunately this does not seem to work with more than one part being removed

Answer (score 0):

Just one more solution:

```
  function splitParts(str, parts) {
    return str
      .split('-')
      .slice(0, str.split('-').length - parts)
      .join('-');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is exactly the same as @CertainPerformance's.